# Android: How to prevent service from restarting after crashing?

Tags: android

Is there a way to prevent my Service from automatically being restarted by ActivityManager after it "crashes"? In some scenarios, I forcefully kill my service on program exit, but do not want Android to keep restarting it.

Comment: Show your skeleton implementation of the service.

Comment: Is it a regular Service or an IntentService?

Answer (score 32):

This behavior is defined by the return value of `onStartCommand()` in your `Service` implementation.  The constant `START_NOT_STICKY` tells Android not to restart the service if it s running while the process is "killed".  In other words:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We don't want this service to continue running if it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return not sticky.
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

HTH

Comment: It wont work if there are outstanding intents. I have that problem and the above approach does not work. The approach below maybe a better alternative but I have not implemented it yet. Have tried other approaches suggested in stack overflow but they have not yet succeeded.

Comment: @BrianReinhold your issue sounds like it has a specific twist on this question, have you posted one of your own explaining your use case and the problems you've observed?  I'd be interested to look into it more.

Comment: At this time I have tried everything I can think of solve this problem that I have found on Stack overflow and elsewhere (I am guessing it is Intents though I don't know). I have tried shared preferences, a static global, START_NON_STICKY and stopSelf() in the create() and onStartCommand() in all combinations and nothing stops the system from restarting the service. What maybe unique is that I am stopping the service in the ACTION_SHUTDOWN Broadcast event. After the service's onDestroy() returns the service's onCreate is called and the main activity restarts. Then the tablet turns off.

Comment: To add, if I don't call stopService in the ACTION_SHUTDOWN event everything is normal but I don't get the behavior I need (the service onDestroy is never called when the system is powered off. It's probably due to total corruption of the system by calling stopService() in the BroadcastReceiver's handler of the event.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution I came up with in case it could help someone else. My app still restarted even with `START_NOT_STICKY`. So instead i check to see if the intent is `null` which means the service was restarted by the system.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Ideally, this method would simply return START_NOT_STICKY and the service wouldn't be
    // restarted automatically. Unfortunately, this seems to not be the case as the log is filled
    // with messages from BluetoothCommunicator and MainService after a crash when this method
    // returns START_NOT_STICKY. The following does seem to work.
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand()");
    if (intent == null) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Service was stopped and automatically restarted by the system. Stopping self now.");
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I had requirement of fetching frequent location updates and send it to server from service. I implemented this via notification based foreground service, but it stopped receiving location updates, whenever application closed. After 2 days struggle, I reached to your answer and tweaked your code. Before `stopSelf()`, I configured restart of same service using `AlarmManager` after a delay of say 10sec for now. And, this worked very well, now getting location updates from the service continuously. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that onCreate is called before onStartCommand and there's no way to access the intent in onCreate unless a new thread is started and waits for a signal from the onStartCommand method. But it's probably overkill since a much easier method would be to move the code from onCreate into onStartCommand

Answer (score 1):

Your service can store a value in the SharedPreferences. For example you can store something like this everytime your service starts:
store("serviceStarted", 1);

When your service terminates regulary (you send a message to do so) you override this value:
store("serviceStarted", 0);

When the next time your service restarts itself it detects that the serviceStarted value is "1" - that means that your service wasnt stopped regulary and it restarted itself. When you detect this your service can call: stopSelf(); to cancel itself.

For more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle